# Optimising some SQL to get all rows corresponding to the minimum value of a column

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I've worked out how to get some rows from a table where a column has the lowest possible value. Note this can return multiple rows, which is what I want. It works just fine.

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM TableA
WHERE col4=0
    AND col5=1
    AND col3 IN
       (SELECT MIN(col3)
        FROM TableA
        WHERE col4=0 AND col5=1)
```

But is the nested select overkill, i.e. can this be optimised? Maybe there's a simple SQL command I'm missing...

I tried

```
SELECT col1, col2, MIN(col3)
FROM TableA
WHERE col4=0
    AND col5=1
```

but this will only ever return one row.

Comment: Efficient group-wise max (or min):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) provides a couple ways to get what you want, which will perform well.

```
SELECT TableA.col1, TableA.col2
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
    MIN(col3) AS col3
    FROM TableA
    WHERE col4 = 0
    AND col5 = 1
) lowest_col3_TableA
ON lowest_col3_TableA.col3 = TableA.col3
WHERE TableA.col4=0
AND TableA.col5=1
```

Or

```
SELECT TableA.col1, TableA.col2
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA lower_col3_TableA
ON lower_col3_TableA.col4 = 0
AND lower_col3_TableA.col5 = 1
AND lower_col3_TableA.col3 < TableA.col3
WHERE TableA.col4=0
AND TableA.col5=1
AND lower_col3_TableA.col3 IS NULL
```

For this second query, the last line of `AND lower_col3_TableA.col3 IS NULL` doesn't necessarily need to be `col3`, but DOES need to be a column that is defined with `NOT NULL`. Usually the leftmost part of the primary key is best.